# UK Visitor Visa for my son who is 1 years old - address needs to be at least 2 years long

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I am applying for visitor visa to the UK. I will be travelling with my wife and my son who is 1.5 years old.

I started filling the application form using the standard visitor visa form. In the address section when I wrote he is been living on the address for 16 months - the form does not let me proceeded to next stage as it says the minimum address history needs to be 2 years.

What can I do about this?

Comment: Say two years to make the computer happy and write an explanation on a free-form sheet that you enclose with the application?

Answer (score 2):

You can add **up to 9 months** without lying, I suppose.

- this is a **Form validation logic error**, which does not check the **age** of the person during the field check

at some point they will notice this and change it. Until then some form of valid answer shold be given to complete the form.

This could then be **mentioned** during an interview in case they are not aware of the problem.

Comment: On what basis do you say that? Do you have a source?

Comment: @Re The child lives with the mother. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pregnancy

Comment: so this isn't a real answer.

Comment: @ReddHerring When the goal is to be **able** to **complete** the application truthfully, it is an answer.